# Flutter app - Warning: CocoaPods not installed. Skipping pod install?

Tags: ios, flutter, xcode

I could not run my flutter app after upgrading the xcode to `Version 15.0`

```
Launching lib/main.dart on iPhone 15 in debug mode...
Warning: CocoaPods not installed. Skipping pod install.
  CocoaPods is used to retrieve the iOS and macOS platform side's plugin code that responds to your plugin usage on the Dart side.
  Without CocoaPods, plugins will not work on iOS or macOS.
  For more info, see https://flutter.dev/platform-plugins
To install see https://guides.cocoapods.org/using/getting-started.html#installation for instructions.
```

CocoaPods not installed or not in valid state.
Error launching application on iPhone 15.

**Podfile**

```
# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
# platform :ios, '11.0'

# CocoaPods analytics sends network stats synchronously affecting flutter build latency.
ENV['COCOAPODS_DISABLE_STATS'] = 'true'

project 'Runner', {
  'Debug' => :debug,
  'Profile' => :release,
  'Release' => :release,
}

def flutter_root
  generated_xcode_build_settings_path = File.expand_path(File.join('..', 'Flutter', 'Generated.xcconfig'), __FILE__)
  unless File.exist?(generated_xcode_build_settings_path)
    raise "#{generated_xcode_build_settings_path} must exist. If you're running pod install manually, make sure flutter pub get is executed first"
  end

  File.foreach(generated_xcode_build_settings_path) do |line|
    matches = line.match(/FLUTTER_ROOT\=(.*)/)
    return matches[1].strip if matches
  end
  raise "FLUTTER_ROOT not found in #{generated_xcode_build_settings_path}. Try deleting Generated.xcconfig, then run flutter pub get"
end

require File.expand_path(File.join('packages', 'flutter_tools', 'bin', 'podhelper'), flutter_root)

flutter_ios_podfile_setup

target 'Runner' do
  platform :ios, '11.0'
  use_frameworks!
  use_modular_headers!

  flutter_install_all_ios_pods File.dirname(File.realpath(__FILE__))
  target 'RunnerTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
  end
end

post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    flutter_additional_ios_build_settings(target)
  end
end
```

Comment: Hi @Anand Did you install cocoapods in your mac. IF not use this command to install cocoapods.

sudo gem install cocoapods

Comment: yes its already installed

Comment: Then try to remove and reinstall it.